# Totvs Fluig - Customização - Chamada em serviço REST no evento beforeSendData

Tags: javascript, node.js

Alguém sabe como faço para realizar uma chamada a um serviço REST dentro do evento beforeSendData, segue abaixo meu código (não funcional):

O meu objetivo é executar uma chamada em um serviço REST do próprio fluig a fim de obter o detalhe de uma solicitação (instância de processo).

Tentei usar a chamada padrão do jQuery mas não funcionou, este script roda do lado servidor.

```js
function beforeSendData(customFields, customFacts) {
      log.info("****************teste");      
      customFields[0] = "1";
      customFacts[0] = 10.53;      
      var processInstanceId = getValue("WKNumProces"); 
      var taskUserId = getValue("WKUser");     
      log.info("****************teste");
//Tentei usar esta API mas não funciona
//Tentei usar jQuery mas também não funcionou.
      WCMAPI.Read({
        type: "POST",
        url: WCMAPI.getServerURL() + '/ecm/api/rest/ecm/workflowView/findDetailsMyRequests?processInstanceId=' + processInstanceId + "&taskUserId=" + taskUserId,
        async: false,
        success: function funcao(data) {
            log.info(txt);
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(txt);        
        },
        error: function (msg){
            log.info("****Não funcionou********");
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: Sim, no log aparece a mensagem informando que WCMAPI não está definida.

ReferenceError: "WCMAPI" is not defined.

Comment: Evento de processo, pretendo pegar informações da tarefa do processo pra saber se está expirada para alimentar o analytics.

Comment: @EduardoSeixas não funciona, o problema é que a variável global WCMAPI não está disponível no scopo, quando faço o que você sugeriu aparece a seguinte mensagem no log.
´13:42:36,743 ERROR [com.datasul.technology.webdesk.customization.CustomizationManager] (http-pool-threads - 8) ERRO AO EXECUTAR SCRIPT -> NOK - sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "WCMAPI" is not defined. (<Unknown source>#48) in <Unknown source> at line number 48´

Comment: Neste artigo [http://tdn.totvs.com/display/public/fluig/Desenvolvimento+de+Eventos#DesenvolvimentodeEventos-WorkflowTasksVO] eu poderia fazer uso deste VO para obter os dados, porém ele também não está disponível no escopo.

Comment: Eu preciso obter dados do processo, neste caso preciso saber se a atividade que está sendo executada está dentro do SLA ou se está atrasada.

Existem vários métodos disponíveis na variavel global hAPI mas nenhum que está documento trás essa informação.

Comment: O método fillStatusTask exige login e senha do usuário que se deseja obter as tarefas atrasadas.

De qualquer forma, estes dados são para o analytics, eu tenho que pegar no evento da tarefa para enviar na menor granularidade possível. Item por item.
Se o objeto WorkflowTasksVO estivesse disponivel em eventos de processos resolveria o meu problema, ou se a api javascript server permitir que eu chame um webservice eu chamaria o url /ecm/api/rest/ecm/workflowView/findDetailsMyRequests passando o id do processo e o id do usuário.

Comment: Seria uma quebra de segurança se o sistema deixar eu pegar a senha do usuário logado atualmente.

Você provavelmente utiliza um usuário/senha padrão para operações de sistema.

Comment: Eu não consigo pegar a senha mesmo que criptografada do usuário, e mesmo se conseguisse pegar criptografada não valeria pois o sistema iria criptografar novamente para validar o usuário e o login iria falhar.

Pelo visto não há uma forma de chamar um endereço (url) através do Javascript server side do Fluig.

Comment: Vou tentar implementar um webservice Java e chamá-lo através do javascript, assim eu farei o ws requisitar o URL, obter as informações e repassar para o js.

Estarei dando uma volta enorme pra uma coisa que considera simples, porém não vi outro caminho.

Comment: Descobri que utilizam no Fluig a engine Javascript Rhino, desta forma eu consigo executar o seguinte código fazendo uso da API java e apache:

`code`
var url = "http://google.com.br";
var get = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod(url);
var client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient();
var br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(get.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
var response = "";
var line = br.readLine();
while(line != null){
 response = response + line;
 line = br.readLine();
}
log.info(response);
get.releaseConnection();
`code`

Comment: Desculpe a demora, sim, resolvi.

Comment: Resolvi da forma especificada acima utilizando a API Java como descrevi no comentário em 02/12/15.
Agradeço a dedicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformei seu comentário em resposta, assim a pergunta não fica sem resposta, e pode ajudar outras pessoas. Aceite como correta, se for o caso.
Fiz as correções nas declarações de variáveis, você não precisa colocar var em todas, basta no início, separando com vírgula.

```
var url = "google.com.br",
get = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod(url),
client = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient(),
br = new java.io.BufferedReader(newjava.io.InputStreamReader(get.getResponseBodyAsStream())),
response = "",
line = br.readLine();
 while(line != null)
 {
   response = response + line; 
   line = br.readLine()
 } 

log.info(response); 
get.releaseConnection();
```